# Co-prime Number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As my knowledge, if there are only two numbers and their there GCD is 1, then they will be relatively coprime , so 10 and 4, they are not relatively co-prime, cause their GCD is 2. Am I right?

Purpose: I have to do a computer program that will check if the two inputed numbers are relatively coprime or not, as a part of an online test. They have a test case that is showing that 10 and 4 are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the definition of relatively prime or co-prime is that the GCD is $1$, $10$ and $4$ are not relatively prime because their GCD is $2$.

Comment: i think so, but i am not understanding why they have told it that they r co-prime.

Comment: Either they made a mistake, or you misunderstood something on the site.

Comment: u  r right, i misunderstood, actually i have to find out how many  co-prime it has till that number.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but if you're feeling uncertain, it wouldn't hurt to review the concept from the ground up: GCD means "greatest common divisor." Your knowledge is confirmed by this Mathworld page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html

The divisors of $4$ are $1, 2, 4$. The divisors of $10$ are $1, 2, 5, 10$. As you can see, $1, 2$ are on both lists, and $2$ is the greatest of those divisors in common.

Maybe the test case has a typo. For example, they might have meant to type $4$ and $103$ but left out the $3$.